# Get notified when a a new calendar is created in Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I read about the [push notifications for a particular Google calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), where a POST request is sent to a preset endpoint URL notifying of any changes (new events, event changes) in a particular calendar.

Are there push notifications in Google API for when a new calendar is created or a particular calendar is deleted? Or do I have to retort to polling the Google calendar API for such changes every once in a while?